# ADX - create table based-on - without throwing error when it already exists

Tags: .net, azure, azure-data-explorer, kql

I'm using the .NET SDK to create tables in Azure Data Explorer. I'm creating the tables based on a template like this:

```
_kustoAdminClient.ExecuteControlCommand("mydb", ".create table my_new_table based-on my_template_table with (folder='/')");
```

This all works as long as the table does not yet exist. So I'm looking for some easy way to ignore the fact if the table is already there. There is `.create-merge table` but that does not work with `based-on`.

Should I just catch the exception and discard it or is there a better way, directly in kql?

Comment: This is currently not supported, but in about 2-3 weeks you will be able to add the `ifnotexists` keyword before the `with` clause to achieve this. The [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-explorer/kusto/management/create-table-based-on-command) should reflect this in due time

Comment: ah, perfect timing then @YoniL. :) would you mind posting an answer here once thats out, so everybody can find it?

Comment: the `ifnotexists` option should be available now (docs are up to date)

Comment: awesome news! feel free to post a new answer @YoniL.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can specify the `ifnotexists` option (see [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-explorer/kusto/management/create-table-based-on-command))